# View the Visual Basic Code (VBA) when the workbook is closed on launch of the same workbook

Tags: vba, excel

By mistake I wrote code that will close the workbook when it is opened.

Because of this I am unable to see the code in order to fix it. How do I edit the code?

Answer (score 4):

open Excel, go in and disable macros from the Trust Center, then open your workbook and remove the offending line of code.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-documents-HA010031071.aspx

Comment: I disabled the macros but still the VBA code behind it is working and can't access the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening some workbook and click alt + F11 to see the macro window. Then open your workbook and it should be ok.

Alternatively, try switching off the macros in Excel so that no macros could run. Then open your workbook.